# Java library for extracting audio information from MP3 files

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Is there any freely available library (other than java media framework) that I can use to extract the bit rate (eg. 128 kbps, VBR) and the audio quality (eg 44.1KHz, Stereo) from a MP3 file?

I would like a standalone library that I can incorporate into my application jar, to be deployed on older Macs too that have only Java 1.5 available and I can't get them upgraded or add any big Java library to.

Just to clarify: I will not play, transcode or do anything of the sort with the audio stream itself, I am interested in the metadata only.

Comment: I have a library/code that does just that but there are many examples on the web that shows you how to read MP3 information from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confess I do not know much about MP3 files, but you can see  from [the format specification](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html) that all the informations needed are in the 32 bits long header of the file.

You could open the MP3 with a `FileInputStream`, read the first 4 bytes of the file and, using some simple binary masks, retrieve the informations you need. IMHO using a specialized library for that is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: It's not just reading only first 4 bytes, but also to verify that the data is an MPEG frame too.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/), plain simple and easy to use, the data you are looking for is into `MP3AudioHeader` class, with methods like `getBitRate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LAMEOnJ library:

- http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/

This java library is light but **you must have the LAMELib installed on target computer**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a java programmer, but i'm pretty sure you could read the mp3 file into a byte array then see http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html for frame info.

Answer (score 0):

This [format specification](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) shows you what's contained the MPEG (mp3) header. You can write code to retrieve this header.